# Assertion error in f = open_input_file("sample", "rb"):

Tags: python, python-3.x, assert

Here in the below code sample.txt has one\ntwo\nthree\nfour respectively.
Last line gives assertion error but when I run on console I get

```
.b'one\r\ntwo\r\nthree\r\nfour\r\nfive\r\n'
```

> What actually is happening with .b in the last statement?

How do I fix this bug

```
 f = open_input_file("sample.txt", "rb")
lines = f.readlines()
assert [b'one\r\n', b'two\r\n', b'three\r\n', b'four\r\n', b'five\r\n'] == lines
f.seek(0, 0)
data = f.read()
assert ".b'one\r\ntwo\r\nthree\r\nfour\r\nfive\r\n'" == data
```

Comment: `"b'stuff'"` is quite different from `b'stuff'`.

Comment: How can you *possibly* get `.b'one\r\ntwo\r\nthree\r\nfour\r\nfive\r\n'` as output? If that were the content of the file, the first assertion wouldn't pass. Something doesn't add up.

Comment: just use `.join("")`